# Using local workspaces with TFS2012/VS2012: can I change the default lock type for checkouts?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, workspace

Our team is using local workspaces. I know server workspaces provide better locking functionality, but the "check in lock" that is possible with local workspaces is sufficient for us. It's a bit of a hassle though, because for non-source files (typically, .rpt files) we have to:

1. Get the latest version of the file.
2. "Check Out For Edit".
3. Change the lock type to "Check in - Allow other users to check out but prevent them from checking in".

Is it possible to, at least, change the default lock type for certain file types (.rpts) so that #3 above is done automatically? Ideally, it would be nice if this applied to automatic check-outs as well, if VS is configured to check out automatically when editing/saving.

Comment: Why *not* use server workspaces in this case? What advantage does local workspaces provide to you if they always hit the server to lock a file?

Comment: We don't want this functionality for every file type; we only want it for binary files. We want to stick with local workspaces because (from my understanding) it should generally be faster until the solution contains around 100K files.

Comment: Why do you have binaries in source control? Would locking the permissions on the files to be "read only" for most users and/or modernizing your dependency management solution solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified what type of binaries I'm talking about - this is mainly for rpt (Crystal Reports) files. I'll edit my question. Changesets that include modifications being made to these rpt files typically include view/stored procedure and possibly C# modifications. I don't think using a dependency management solution would help, and making the files read only wouldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know this is an old post and I'm not sure of the differences between VS2012 with TFS2012 and VS2015 with TFS2015, but I thought I'd share my solution, in case it help you or anyone else.

While there is not an option to completely automatically "Check-in lock" a file when you edit it that I can find, I did find that you could have it prompt for the check-in lock with that lock already selected.

**MY SOLUTION:**

You go `Tools > Options` then select the `Source Control > Environment` and under `Editing` select **"Prompt for lock on checkout"**

[image]

**Now when ever you open a file and begin editing it, the moment you make a change it will pop up a window like this:**

[image]

> Note: that it has the lock type set to the check-in lock
>   automatically. If you had selected the "Prompt for check out" selected
>   in the options form, it would pop up the same for, but with the
>   "Unchanged" option selected.
>
> One other important thing to note, is if you hit cancel in the Check
>   Out form, it will proceed to edit the file, but without checking it
>   out, which may be undesirable.

That covers your Points #2 and #3

**As for point #1**

Again, I don't know about VS2012 and TFS2012, but with 2015 you go to:`Team Explorer > Settings > Source Contol (under the team project node)`

[image]

You then check **"Enable Get Latest on Check Out"**

[image]

After both settings have been changed:

1. You can check out a file just by starting to edit it
2. The program will get the latest file when you check it out.
3. And it will show a prompt confirming the check-in lock before check out.

Again I'm aware that this answer is coming a little late, and it is done using 2015 software not 2012, but I hope it applies for you, and perhaps this post will help someone else.